# How to Grouping Key and Value using ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, grouping

I have a list item with Key and Value pair. I have binding the Key in list box its display the correct output. But Value is not showing. I know this is very basic question. I am New for WPF. I have referred many sites and answers But I don't know where I have done mistake on my code. Please anybody help me to achieve this. My sample code is mentioned below,

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ListBox
    Name="memberCollection"
    Grid.Row="0"
    MinWidth="150"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    BorderThickness="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MainValues}">

    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
                                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>                        
</ListBox>
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public MainViewModel(TestCollection testCollection)
{
    MainValues = new ObservableCollection<Details>();
    TestCollections = testCollection;

    foreach (var _val in TestCollection.GroupingMainCollection)
    {
        MainValues.Add(new Details() { Key = _val.Key, Values = _val.Value});
    }

    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainValues);
    PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Key");
    view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

}
```

**DetailsModel**

```
public class Details 
{     
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<IValue> Values { get; set; }
}
```

**IValue**

```
public interface IValue
{
    string Name { get; set; }            
    string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to display `Values` collection in group header but under group content, so move `ItemsControl` from under Expander header and set it as `ItemTemplate`.

Here is working code:

```
<ListBox
                        Name="memberCollection"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        MinWidth="150"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MainValues}">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: Grouping ListItem Selection Issue Screenshot]

**Edit:**
If I understand you correctly, you want to display collection of items and then choose only single item within collection of collection of items!

Checkout code below which uses `ItemsControl` instead of using `ListView/ListBox`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MainValues}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" Margin="5">
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>

                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" 
                                BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />
                    </Expander>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I have one issue when selecting the grouping item. When I mouse over or select the item, It select the all item. I want to select only one item for drag and drop. Please give any suggestion to select the single item of grouping list item.

Comment: If you want that behavior, you are better off with using `ListView` instead of a `ListBox`. You can try a heck of disabling selection on list item but it will be nasty.

Comment: Just for your reference: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/

Comment: I used listview as per your reference link. But the value collection is not displaying on the **GridViewColumn**. Please give any suggestion how to display the dictionary value collection on the GridViewColumn.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. When I used your edited solution the key value only display, value items are not displayed.

Comment: @sameer Chaeck for any binding errors, posted code is working fine for me with your provided ViewModel.